# How to set Stripe Wallet buttons to always visible?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I'm integrating Stripe Wallet in Next.js, the wallet buttons show up, but only one is visible by default and others are hidden.

[image]

When clicking the `See more` button, it shows the GooglePay and ApplePay buttons.
[image]

What I want is to show the GPay and Apple Pay buttons always visible.
This is what I have now for the wallet buttons.

```
<div id="checkout-page">
  <ExpressCheckoutElement
    onConfirm={onConfirm}
    options={{
      wallets: { applePay: "always", googlePay: "always" },
      layout: { maxColumns: 0, maxRows: 0 },
    }}
    onClick={onClick}
  />
  {errorMessage && <div>{errorMessage}</div>}
</div>
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thank you!

PS: Some helps docs below:
https://stripe.com/docs/elements/express-checkout-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `layout: { overflow:"never", ... }`  is for that : https://stripe.com/docs/js/elements_object/create_express_checkout_element#express_checkout_element_create-options-layout-overflow

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @karllekko, let me try that now!

Comment: It worked, thank you! `layout: { maxColumns: 1, maxRows: 0, overflow: "never" },`